# How to set height of the Windows Form forcefully?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-forms-designer

I want to set windows form height when I maximize form. I have used Resize Event.
Resize event call automatically when I minimize/restore windows.
Following is my code.

```
int FormHeight = 260;
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.height = FormHeight;
}
```

Above code is working fine if size is change when form is open on screen. But when I minimize form, form height is 28px and I can't change it by this.height = FormHeight;
How can I assign this.height forcefully?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have 1 form and in that form I add usercontrol. It can be 1 or more usercontrols. It add and remove dynamically. 
When it add, I need to increase height of form and when it remove, I need to decrease height of form @Luaan

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work while the window is minimized. However, using `MinimumSize` would probably work better, and it should work even when the form is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MaximumSize` property. If you want to restrict the hight only, use it like this:

```
   MaximumSize = new Size(Int32.MaxValue, 260);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. When the form is minimized, it kind of stops existing for some purposes - for example, it no longer has any client area. That's why the form height is 28px in your case - only the borders actually "exist".

This is just a part of the complex system that handles window rendering - you cannot draw to the form when it's minimized, you can't capture it's contents (remember, there is no client area)...

Raymond has great posts on the topic on his blog - for example, [Where did windows minimize to before the task bar was invented?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/28/249044.aspx) and [Why do minimized windows have an apparent size of 160x31?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/10/370445.aspx), as well as [Obtaining a window's size and position while it is minimized](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/07/175285.aspx).